# Getting 'Cannot read property 'ɵmod' of undefined' when importing custom module

Tags: javascript, angular, package, angular-library

I've built and published a custom components library, kept in Artifactory, to install into my app? I'm getting the following error after I install the library, when the app loads. Like nothing renders, just this error message...

> core.js:1139 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod') at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1139) at recurse (core.js:25270) at recurse (core.js:25281) at registerNgModuleType (core.js:25266) at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25380) at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:28993) at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:29239) at Module.zUnb (main.ts:11) at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:79) at Object.0 (main.js:11)

I have seen the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586956/getting-cannot-read-property-%C9%B5mod-of-undefined-when-importing-custom-module) stating to "return the module" by adding... but I have no idea what file it needs to be added to.

```
{ path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module') .then((a) => { return a.AuthModule; }); },
```

And I have confirmed the proper folders are packaged when the library is built as mentioned in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740378/angular-library-cannot-read-property-%C9%B5mod-of-undefined)

Also, this is my import statement, that I feel is wrong. But I get a compile error if I use "@myOrg_amf/amf-library"

```
import { AmfLibraryModule, MaterialModule } from '@myOrg_amf/amf-library/projects/amf-library/src/public-api';
```

Thank you for any advice you can give on this.

Comment: As far as I have ever encountered this problem it was always related to angular main dependencies versions issue. The import you wrote seems wrong to me too. Usually imports related to a library are most likely something like import { Something } from "@yourLib/library-selector";. I would suggest you to check how you'are building your library, I'm pretty sure the problem is located there. I believe that if you remove all the custom library references (even from the package.json) your app will compile succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error and I tried the mentioned solution (i simplified the syntax a bit but just check that you're actually returning the module if you use the curly braces in the `then()` block:

```
{ path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then((a) => a.AuthModule) },
```

For those who have no idea how to place this, it should go inside the `app.routing.module.ts` file, or wherever you're setting up your routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then((a) => a.AuthModule) },
  ...
];


@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In this way the module will be loaded only when the matching route is active.
For more info see https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Anyway, in my case I get always the same error, the only difference is that now it appears when I navigate on that route instead of being displayed as the app starts, meaning that it's thrown when angular tries to load the module.

I tried to point directly to the module in my import url (instead of public-api as it's shown here) but this didn't fix the issue.

Probably I did something odd in my library :/ hope this helped at least for the first doubt

UPDATE:
I was calling `npm publish` from `projects/my-project` folder (which holds `src` etc), instead it should be called from `dist/my-project`. Now the error disappeared.

Comment: I am a bit unsure if you did find a solution to suggest and an answer, from what I read, your are reproducing the problem? in such case it is not an answer.

Comment: I just gave an answer to the first doubt, since I didn't have one for the main question at that time. Anyway I updated it with my solution, hope it will help someone

Comment: Just sharing thoughts here @gmasala and maybe starting with question any update also gets me a bit off. If You know the problem, which it sort of looks like you do. it would be a good idea to start with 'the problem could be ...' 'it was when i encountered similar error description' ... 'in that case my solution was' ... and get the filling out perhaps. Like i tried x which didn't work ... not required, could be in a comment if you wish. But you did solve the first part of the problem/ doubt I'd focus my solution on that to get at least partial solve accepted.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I never answered before so I'm new to this. Will apply your suggestions next time for sure!